# Is there a name for digraphs with at most $n$ vertices and exactly $n-1$ arcs?

Tags: graph-theory

I noticed these graphs have some interesting properties, which I'm not really sure how to prove rigorously (I have minimal formal math education), but seem to be intuitively true.

For example, it seems that the sum of Eulerian trails in all the classes of graphs with at most $n$ vertices and exactly $n-1$ arcs is equal to the Bell number $B_n$. Additionally, the sum of Eulerian trails in all the classes of graphs with exactly $m \leq n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges is equal to the Stirling number of the second kind ${n \brace m}$.

To see this, map the graphs to "sorted" restricted growth strings (i.e., in the string $\langle a_1,a_2,...,a_n \rangle$, $a_{i+1} \leq \max(a_1,a_2,...,a_i)+1$). The vertices are numbered arbitrarily from $0$ to $v-1$ where $v$ is the total number of vertices. Then, each pair in the restricted growth string represents an arc. That is, in the string $\langle a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n \rangle$, the arcs are $\{a_1 \to a_2, a_2 \to a_3, ..., a_{n-1} \to a_n\}$. Each of these strings represents a unique Eulerian trail. So the total number of Eulerian trails corresponds to the number of partitions of a set of size $n$, or $B_n$. The total number of Eulerian trails for a given $m \leq n$ would correspond to the number of $m$-partitions of a set of size $n$, or ${n \brace m}$.

Correct me if I've made any errors or anything isn't clear enough. It's very interesting to me and if these graphs have a name I'd like to read more about them.

Comment: Do you mean **trees**?

Comment: @Achilles, not quite. These graphs can have cycles and parallel edges. Although the fact that you asked the question implies that perhaps I haven't been clear enough. What suggested to you that I was talking about trees, if you don't mind me asking?